# find + delete files with date format

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, find

we have the following logs

```
/var/log/sync/manager.log.2018-06-14-00
/var/log/sync/manager.log.2020-01-14-07
/var/log/sync/manager.log.2020-01-14-02
/var/log/sync/manager.log.2020-01-14-03
/var/log/sync/manager.log.2020-01-14-04
/var/log/sync/manager.log.2020-01-14-34
/var/log/sync/manager.log.2020-01-10-06
/var/log/sync/manager.log.2020-01-14-04
/var/log/sync/manager.log.2019-04-14-05
/var/log/sync/manager.log.2020-01-14-06
/var/log/sync/manager.log.2020-01-14-76
/var/log/sync/manager.log.2020-01-14-982
```

we want to delete the logs with date format as example - `2020-01-14-06`

I created the following

```
find  var/log/sync/  -type f -mmin +60  -regex '.*\.log.*[0-9]$' -delete
```

but its delete evry ended number after ".log."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
d='[0123456789]'
LC_ALL=C find /var/log/sync -name "*.log.$d$d$d$d-$d$d-$d$d-$d$d" \
  -type f -mmin +59 -delete
```

(note that `-mmin` and `-delete` are non-standard extension).

With GNU `find`, to delete files that are more than 60 minutes old, it's `-mmin +59` (or `\( -mmin 60 -o -mmin +60 \)`).

Comment: we prefer to use --delete not rm -f

Comment: actually I need to add it to cron job under /etc/cron.d  ,  so not if we can use LC_ALL=C

Comment: @yael, not sure what you mean. cron jobs spawn `sh` to interpret the job command lines, and that syntax above is standard `sh` syntax. You can omit the `LC_ALL=C` if you can guarantee the file names will be valid sequences of characters regardless of the locale (which from your sample looks likely).

Comment: what U think about - find  var/log/sync/  -type f -mmin +60  -regex '.*\.log.*[0-9]+$' -delete  ( from Jetchisel )

Comment: about the -mmin , since we want also to delete the files after 24 hours , can we use  -mtime +1  with -delete?

Comment: @yael, that would be `-mtime +0` for files not modified in the last 24 hours with GNU and POSIX `find` (not modern BSD). `-mtime +1` would be for file not modified in the last 48 hours. See also `! -newermt '24 hours ago'` in GNU/BSD (not POSIX)

Answer (score 1):

I think your regular expression is not OK. You have `.*\` after log, which means everything after log is fine and then a number at the end. It should be:

```
find var/log/sync/ -type f -mmin +60 -regextype sed -regex '.*\.log\.[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2,3\}$' -delete
```

`-regextype sed` is needed at least on my computer to enable quantificators e.g. `\{2\}`.

Comment: so just to add the option -delete to remove all match files?

Comment: @yael Yes, I forgot to add `-delete` when I was testing the command.

Comment: see the update of the question

Comment: last number could be as manager.log.2020-01-14-982

Comment: @yael I changed the last quantificator in the answer to `\{2,3\}`, which means 2 to 3 digits.